# prepareForSegue out of custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

I have a new problem waiting for a solution. I have a little bit wired layout now. My MainView is a TableView, in one of the 6 custom cells is one cell that have a TableView in it. By clicking on a cell of this inner tableView I want a segue to a new YTPlayerViewController, a view for watching a youtube video using googles YThelper classes.

The problem is, that `performSegueWithIdentifier` and `override func prepareForSegue` stuff doesn't work because I have to handle them in my custom UITableViewCell class that don't know these functions.

Is there any alternative?

I just want to transfer my videoId from the cell to the YTPlayerViewController, open it and play the Video. From there it should be possible to go back.

hope you guys can understand and help me.

Greetings from germany

My Class:

```
class DetailVideoCell: UITableViewCell , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var selectedVideoIndex: Int!



    /*override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showPlayer" {
            let playerViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! YTPlayerViewController
            playerViewController.videoID = Data.youTubeVideos[selectedVideoIndex]["videoId"] as! String
        }
    }*/



    // MARK: TableViewDataSource functions.

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Data.youTubeVideos.count ?? 3
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: VideoDetailCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("VideoDetailCell") as! VideoDetailCell

        let url = NSURL(string: Data.youTubeVideos[indexPath.row]["thumbnail"] as! String)
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
        let image = UIImage(data: data!)

        cell.videoThumbnail.image = image
        cell.channelTitle.text = Data.youTubeVideos[indexPath.row]["channelTitle"] as? String
        cell.videoTitle.text = Data.youTubeVideos[indexPath.row]["title"] as? String

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        selectedVideoIndex = indexPath.row
        print(selectedVideoIndex)
        //performSegueWithIdentifier("showPlayer", sender: indexPath)
    }

}
```

Comment: why that stuff didn't work ? You have to handl them in your tableView controller class and not in the tablecell subclass.

Comment: Yeah but my tableview controller is my tableviewcell

Comment: Do you implement `UITableViewDelegate` anywhere?

Comment: Yes, just added my code.

Comment: you shoud implement the table delegate methods in the view controller class, and not in table cell class.

Comment: I think you don't read my question. I have a second TableView inside my TableViewCell from another TableView.

Comment: I have no idea how you managed to have a tableview outlet in a tablecell subclass.

Comment: You just define a prototype cell in your storyboard and place a tableView in it. Works fine.

Comment: Create a delegate for your custom tableview cell that will send the identifier to your MainView. Then perform the segue on your MainView with that identifier. [Quick delegation guide](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your DetailVideoCell:

```
// Create a protocol that will act as the delegate

protocol DetailVideoCellDelegate: class {
    func selectedCellAtIndex(index: Int)
}

class DetailVideoCell: UITableViewCell , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var selectedVideoIndex: Int!

// Create a delegate object
weak var delegate: DetailVideoCellDelegate?


/*override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
 if segue.identifier == "showPlayer" {
 let playerViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! YTPlayerViewController
 playerViewController.videoID = Data.youTubeVideos[selectedVideoIndex]["videoId"] as! String
 }
 }*/



// MARK: TableViewDataSource functions.

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Data.youTubeVideos.count ?? 3
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: VideoDetailCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("VideoDetailCell") as! VideoDetailCell

    let url = NSURL(string: Data.youTubeVideos[indexPath.row]["thumbnail"] as! String)
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    let image = UIImage(data: data!)

    cell.videoThumbnail.image = image
    cell.channelTitle.text = Data.youTubeVideos[indexPath.row]["channelTitle"] as? String
    cell.videoTitle.text = Data.youTubeVideos[indexPath.row]["title"] as? String

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedVideoIndex = indexPath.row
    print(selectedVideoIndex)

    // use the delegate to send the selected index back to your MainView
    delegate?.selectedCellAtIndex(selectedVideoIndex)
    //performSegueWithIdentifier("showPlayer", sender: indexPath)
    }

}
```

In your MainView:

```
class MainView: DetailVideoCellDelegate {

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // However you are configuring your cells set the DetailVideoCell delegate to self

    if cell.delegate == nil {
        cell.delegate = self
    }

    return cell
}

func selectedCellAtIndex(index: Int) {

    // Or whatever you are using the index for
    let identifier = yourArray[index]

    // Easiest way is to use a navigation controller to handle the segues to be able to go back
    // Otherwise you will need to do it in a custom way
    self.navigationController?.performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier, sender: self)

    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah! Thank you man. In combination with that link you sended first I solved it. Your code was right, but you have to write the func selectedCellAtIndex inside a extention: "extention MainView: DetailVideoCellDelegate { func selectedCellAtIndex(index: Int) {...}}. Thank You!

Comment: No problem. Also yes you are right that you can put it inside an extension,  but it's not required to do so.

Comment: Without the cell.delegate = self doesn't allowed from the compiler

Comment: Are you adding the DetailVideoCellDelegate protocol to the MainView? It doesn't really matter though, an extension gets the job done too.

Comment: Ah no I didn't you right! Yes I think I let it so, feels cleaner in my case